# Can this ldap filter join be done in one statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory, ldap

I am pulling employee names from active directory for a rails app. It is working overall except that there are some 'non real people' entries that have a cn=people such as 'conference room'. I need to eliminate those. I can do that with an iterative filter join but that seems horribly inefficient and kludgy.

What I have now is

```
    filter1 = (Net::LDAP::Filter.ge( "sn", "a"))
    filter2 = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "givenName", "c*" )
    filter3 = Net::LDAP::Filter.ne("samaccountname", "croom" )
    treebase = "dc=xxxxxx,dc=com"

    joined_filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.join(filter1, filter2)
    joined_filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.join(joined_filter, filter3)

    @temp_search = ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => joined_filter )
```

that gives me all employees with a surname greater than or equal to 'a' (I know that needs to be tweaked) and a given name starting with 'c'. Filter3 excludes the conference room "croom". It seems there should be some way to pass an array into a filter. If I try to pass all three filters to a join, I get a 'wrong number of arguments'

Is there a way to pass multiple exclusions such as 'croom' 'croom2' 'breakroom' etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `Net::LDAP` library it doesn't seem there is a way to pass an array to an `Net::LDAP::Filter` object like you suggest.  However you can join filters using the classes `#&` method.

Something like:

```
filter1 = Net::LDAP::Filter.ge( "sn", "a")
filter2 = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "givenName", "c*" )
filter3 = Net::LDAP::Filter.ne("samaccountname", "croom" )
treebase = "dc=xxxxxx,dc=com"

joined_filter = filter1 & filter2 & filter3

@temp_search = ldap.search(:base => treebase, :filter => joined_filter)
```

Or perhaps a little better:

```
filters = Net::LDAP::Filter.ge( "sn", "a") &
          Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "givenName", "c*" ) &
          Net::LDAP::Filter.ne("samaccountname", "croom" )
treebase = "dc=xxxxxx,dc=com"

@temp_search = ldap.search(:base => treebase, :filter => filters)
```

Looking at the net ldap filter [class](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/blob/master/lib/net/ldap/filter.rb) you can see some of the other convenient methods available.